# stm32 pulse count up mode with reset, why not reset? (two signal reset count and steps)

Tags: counter, stm32, pulse

I make this easy example, with count pulse input TI1 and reset pulse input TI2
when enable reset trigger counter give random numbers!

stm32 driver https://github.com/mbedmicro/mbed/blob/9b7d23d47153c298a6d24de9a415202705889d11/libraries/mbed/targets/cmsis/TARGET_STM/TARGET_STM32L4/stm32l4xx_hal_tim.h

function is like this:

```
 /* Select the TIM_SMCR_TS_1 signal as Input trigger for the TIM */

  htim->Instance->SMCR &= ~TIM_SMCR_TS;
  htim->Instance->SMCR |= TIM_SMCR_TS_1; 

  Use the TIM_SMCR_TS_1 to reset the TIM counter each edge detection */  
  htim->Instance->SMCR &= ~TIM_SMCR_SMS;
  htim->Instance->SMCR |= TIM_SLAVEMODE_RESET;
```

code:

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.h"



//direction to PA_9 -- step pulse to PA_8
uint16_t  count1;

void pulsecount(void)
{
    TIM_HandleTypeDef timer;
    TIM_IC_InitTypeDef ICconfiginit;
    TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef counter;

    TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef SlaveModeselect;

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    __TIM1_CLK_ENABLE();
    __GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8 | GPIO_PIN_9;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_TIM1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    timer.Instance = TIM1;
    timer.Init.Period = 0xffff;
    timer.Init.Prescaler = 0;
    timer.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    timer.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;

    ICconfiginit.ICFilter = 0x0f;
    ICconfiginit.ICPolarity = TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_RISING;
    ICconfiginit.ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
    ICconfiginit.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;

    counter.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_TI1;
    counter.ClockFilter = 0x0f;

    SlaveModeselect.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_RESET;
    SlaveModeselect.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_TI2FP2;

    HAL_TIM_IC_Init(&timer);
    HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&timer, &ICconfiginit, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
    HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&timer, &counter);
    HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchronization(&timer, &SlaveModeselect); ///<<< not reset 
    HAL_TIM_IC_Start(&timer, TIM_CHANNEL_1);


    TIM1->EGR = 1;           // Generate an update event
    TIM1->CR1 = 1;           // Enable the counter
}

int main()
{
        pulsecount();

    while (1) {
        count1=TIM1->CNT;

        printf("%d\r\n", count1);
        wait(1.0);

    };
}
```